# Importing keras-rl package into conda environment

Tags: github, anaconda, spyder, conda, keras-rl

I've installed [keras-rl](https://github.com/matthiasplappert/keras-rl) package on my computer, using their instructions:

```
git clone https://github.com/matthiasplappert/keras-rl.git
cd keras-rl
python setup.py install
```

So my conda environment sees this package, however when I am trying to import it in Spyder as a part of my code, i.e. `import keras-rl`, I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

with a pointer to the dash of keras-rl.

Question: How could I import the keras-rl (or any other package with the dash in the name) in Spyder?

Answer (score 1):

We can install keras-rl by simply executing

```
         pip install keras-rl
```

There are various functionalities from keras-rl that we can make use for running RL based algorithms in a specified environment

few examples below

```
from rl.agents.dqn import DQNAgent
from rl.policy import BoltzmannQPolicy
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory
```

This is how we can use the package.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [examples](https://github.com/matthiasplappert/keras-rl/tree/master/examples) present in the github repository, you will see that the various functionalities are imported from `rl`. Like this:

```
(root) ~/condaexpts/keras-rl/examples $ grep -h import * | grep rl
from rl.agents import ContinuousDQNAgent
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory
from rl.random import OrnsteinUhlenbeckProcess
from rl.core import Processor
from rl.agents.cem import CEMAgent
from rl.memory import EpisodeParameterMemory
from rl.agents import DDPGAgent
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory
from rl.random import OrnsteinUhlenbeckProcess
from rl.agents.dqn import DQNAgent
from rl.policy import LinearAnnealedPolicy, BoltzmannQPolicy, EpsGreedyQPolicy
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory
from rl.core import Processor
from rl.callbacks import FileLogger, ModelIntervalCheckpoint
from rl.agents.dqn import DQNAgent
from rl.policy import BoltzmannQPolicy
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After lots of examination I found the correct way.
You can import RL by writing this:

```
"import rl"
```

and then write your code like:

```
rl.core.Agent()
```